# Adding file name to the counted data

Tags: unix, awk, compare, comparison, string-comparison

Suppose I have files similar to the following.

**file 1**

```
1,144931087,144931087,T,C  
16,89017167,89017167,C,G  
17,7330235,7330235,G,T  
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
```

**file 2**

```
1,144931087,144931087,T,C
16,89017167,89017167,C,G
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
```

**file 3**

```
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
```

I would like to find how many times duplicated values are present in each file, So ideally, the output would be like:

**Output**

```
2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C  
2 16,89017167,89017167,C,G  
3 17,10222478,10222478,C,T  
1 17,7330235,7330235,G,T
```

I used the following command for counting the duplicates value.

```
sort Test1.csv Test2.csv Test3.csv | uniq --count
```

Now I wish to add the file name for the counted output.
My desired output should look like this:

```
Test1 Test2 2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C  
Test1 Test2 2 16,89017167,89017167,C,G  
Test1 Test2 Test 3 3 17,10222478,10222478,C,T  
Test1 1 17,7330235,7330235,G,T
```

Can anyone help me to get the desired output or can anyone suggest me a better way to get my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk. Sorry about my clever file naming scheme:

```
$ awk '{
    a[$0]++                   # count hits
    b[$0]=b[$0] FILENAME " "  # store filenames
}
END {
    for(i in a)               
        print b[i] a[i],i     # output them
}' foo bar baz
foo bar 2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C
foo bar 2 16,89017167,89017167,C,G
foo bar baz 3 17,10222478,10222478,C,T
foo 1 17,7330235,7330235,G,T
```

**UPDATED** per comments:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
} 
{
    a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4]++ 
    b[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4]=b[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4] FILENAME "|"
    c[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4]=$0                      # keep the last record with 
}                                                      # specific key combination 
END { 
    for(i in a) 
        print b[i] "," a[i],c[i]  
}' foo  bar baz
foo|bar|,2,16,89017167,89017167,C
foo|,1,17,7330235,7330235,G
foo|bar|,2,1,144931087,144931087,T
foo|bar|baz|,3,17,10222478,10222478,C
```

Comment: is there any way to add a delimiter before the count for example **foo bar |2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C**

Comment: Sure. Replace the `print ...` with `print b[i] "|" a[i],i` That should do it.

Comment: Ya just did that before I saw your comment.

Comment: can we able to do the same for first 4 columns for example compare for example my file contains 10 columns but I want to compare only the first 4

Comment: You set the delimiters to `,` and instead of processing `$0` you state individually the columns you want to process, ie.  `$1,$2,$3,$4`.

Comment: awk '{
    a[$1,$2,$3,$4]++       # count hits
    b[$0]=b[$0] FILENAME "|"  # store filenames
}
END {
    for(i in a)               
       print b[i] "," a[i],i     # output them
}' Test*.csv **I have changed it but the file name is not printing it is printing some symbols**

Comment: You also need to change the `b[$0]`s.

Comment: awk '
{
    a[$1,$2,$3,$4]++       # count hits
    b[$1,$2,$3,$4]=b[$1,$2,$3,$4] FILENAME "|"  # store filenames
}
END {
    for(i in a)               
       print b[i] "," a[i],i     # output them
}' Test*.csv  ** did the same for b[$0]*** also still im getting some symbols posting the pic in the question

Comment: I got it but the problem it should print all the values but its only printing the selected value.

Comment: So you want to select on `$1-$4` but print all the columns? But which one then if, for example, your files have `1,2,3,4,X` and `1,2,3,4,Y`?

Comment: you have understood it my file can be 1,2,3,4,X and 1,2,3,4,Y I need to compare on the first 4 variables with all the variable if the first 4 variables is repeated it should put the number of repeats including any one of the duplicated 5th value(ie X or Y) if its a unique the file name count and it value ie(1,2,3,8,Z

Comment: So, any one of the records with duplicated `$1-$4`. Coming right up. For simplicity it will be the last one.

Comment: Sure can you explain the lines too, so it will be useful for others

Answer (score 2):

**Input:**

```
more Test*.csv
::::::::::::::
Test1.csv
::::::::::::::
1,144931087,144931087,T,C
16,89017167,89017167,C,G
17,7330235,7330235,G,T
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
::::::::::::::
Test2.csv
::::::::::::::
1,144931087,144931087,T,C
16,89017167,89017167,C,G
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
::::::::::::::
Test3.csv
::::::::::::::
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
```

Command:

```
awk '{tmp[$0]++;if(length(tmp2[$0])==0){tmp2[$0]=FILENAME;next}tmp2[$0]=tmp2[$0] OFS FILENAME}END{for(elem in tmp){print tmp2[elem] OFS tmp[elem] OFS elem}}' Test*.csv
```

Output:

```
Test1.csv Test2.csv 2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C
Test1.csv Test2.csv 2 16,89017167,89017167,C,G
Test1.csv Test2.csv Test3.csv 3 17,10222478,10222478,C,T
Test1.csv 1 17,7330235,7330235,G,T
```

Explanations:

```
  # gawk profile, created Mon Dec 17 14:46:47 2018

  # Rule(s)

   {
           tmp[$0]++ #associative array to count the occurrences freq
           if (length(tmp2[$0]) == 0) {  #when you add the first occurrence filename you do not need to add a space
                   tmp2[$0] = FILENAME
                   next
            }
           #append to variable with a space
           tmp2[$0] = tmp2[$0] OFS FILENAME
    }

    # END rule(s)

    END {
           # loop on each element of the associative arrays and print them
           for (elem in tmp) {
                   print tmp2[elem] OFS tmp[elem] OFS elem
            }
    }
```

The `if...next...` can be replaced by `(length(tmp2[$0]) == 0 ? tmp2[$0] = FILENAME : tmp2[$0] = tmp2[$0] OFS FILENAME)` to simplify the `awk` script into:

```
  {
       tmp[$0]++
       (length(tmp2[$0]) == 0 ? tmp2[$0] = FILENAME : tmp2[$0] = tmp2[$0] OFS FILENAME)
  }

  END {
         for (elem in tmp) {
              print tmp2[elem] OFS tmp[elem] OFS elem
         }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Allan and thanks for your details explanation

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following and this should give you output into Input_file's line's Input occurrence. I have used `gsub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")` since your Input_file(s) have spaces in last of lines so removing them here, you could remove it in case it is NOT the case.

```
awk '
{
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"")
}
!a[$0]++{
  b[++count]=$0
}
{
  c[$0]++
  d[$0]=d[$0]?d[$0] OFS FILENAME:FILENAME
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print d[b[i]]"|"c[b[i]],b[i]
  }
}'  test1 test2 test3
```

Output will be as follows.

```
test1 test2|2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C
test1 test2|2 16,89017167,89017167,C,G
test1|1 17,7330235,7330235,G,T
test1 test2 test3|3 17,10222478,10222478,C,T
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you, you could do upvote for all helpful answers, cheers.

Comment: Sure will do that i have one more doubt can we count the duplicates and file name for first 4 columns

Comment: @ManojkumarK, could you please show me example for it?

Comment: use the sample example as i have given here i want to compare the 1,144931087,144931087 among the 5 columns given in the example now i want to compare only the first 3

Answer (score 1):

One more answer using Perl.

```
> cat file1m.csv
1,144931087,144931087,T,C
16,89017167,89017167,C,G
17,7330235,7330235,G,T
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
> cat file2m.csv 
1,144931087,144931087,T,C
16,89017167,89017167,C,G
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
> cat file3m.csv
17,10222478,10222478,C,T
> cat uniq_perl.ksh
perl -lne ' 
@t=@{ $kvf{$_} };
if( not $ARGV ~~ @t ) { push(@t,$ARGV); $kvf{$_}=[ @t ] ;  }
close(ARGV) if eof; 
END { for(keys %kvf) { @x=@{$kvf{$_}};  print join(" ",@x)." ".scalar(@x)." ".$_  } }   
' file*m*csv 
> ./uniq_perl.ksh
file1m.csv file2m.csv file3m.csv 3 17,10222478,10222478,C,T
file1m.csv 1 17,7330235,7330235,G,T
file1m.csv file2m.csv 2 1,144931087,144931087,T,C
file1m.csv file2m.csv 2 16,89017167,89017167,C,G
>
```